# Why HIbernate's PESEL validator doesn't work?

Tags: java, hibernate

documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.4/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/pl/PESELValidator.html

```
@Test
    public void testEncryptingPesel() {
        // given
        CharSequence validPesel = "94092367705";


        // when
        PESELValidator validator = new PESELValidator();

        // then
        assertTrue(validator.isValid(validPesel, null));
}
```

the test fails. The PESEL is 100% correct, ya can check it here: 
https://sprawdz-numer.com/pesel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you didn't initialize the validator, so it doesn't know which digit is the verification digit.
You have to call the `initialize` method explicitly:

```
// when
PESELValidator validator = new PESELValidator();
validator.initialize(null);
```

The argument is `null` because it's ignored anyway (it's hard to say what was in the mind of the author of this method).